# What's the difference between a TimeStamp field and mysql curdate

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I was working and my friend told me to use `curdate()` on `mysql query` to get the `current date` of the server... And I told him that I was using `Time_Stamp` field for date/time.
Now I start to think, is there a huge difference between this two ways ? One is better than the other?  Or there is something that makes it a not `good practice` ? Also there is a `now()` that can be used too. I just wanted to understand how does it work or wich one is the best and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version:

```
NOW() = CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', CURTIME());
CURDATE() = DATE(NOW());
```

Some explanation:

`NOW()` gets both date (`CURDATE()`) and time (`CURTIME()`).

So if we do it the other way round, `CURDATE() = DATE(NOW())`.

Regarding `timestamp`, in [MySQL Data Types](http://kimbriggs.com/computers/computer-notes/mysql-notes/mysql-data-types-50.file) we can see `timestamp`is 3 bytes, while `datetime` is 8 bytes.

Comment: Nice man, thanks ! And what about the `timestamp field`, is it a better or worse way to go ?

Comment: It depends on what you want. I prefer `timestamp`, although you have to use MySQL date functions to work with it. The `datetime` format is easier to read.

Comment: The field depends in what kind of data you will store and you will search, since you can work in several ways with queries and for e.g., between. I choose for my Expiration/Modified fields the timestamp type with the current timestamp. by the way +1 for the clarify

Comment: Thanks guys for the explanation ! I'll keep using my `Time_Stamp` fields hehe =) +1 for the explanation

Comment: @fedorqui you said `although you have to use MySQL date functions to work with it`. I just set the timestamp field to default and it works perfect, without using any `mysql date functions`.